# Creating a data frame that condense titles to small subset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create a data frame called shot.lookup that takes a bunch of shot types and converts them to a more generalize shot type.  Thus a 2 variable df with specific shot type in one column and generalized shot type in the other. For some reason the following is not giving me a df and for the life of me I cannot figure it out.  Any suggestions or alternative ways.

shot.lookup <-data.frame(Title = c("Alley Oop Dunk Shot", "Alley Oop Layup shot",
                                     "Cutting Dunk Shot", "Driving Dunk Shot", "Dunk Shot", "Putback Dunk Shot", "Running Dunk Shot", "Tip Dunk Shot",
                                     "Driving Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Driving Reverse Layup Shot","Layup Shot", "Putback Layup Shot", "Reverse Layup Shot", "Cutting Layup Shot",
                                     "Running Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Running Layup Shot", "Driving Layup Shot", "Tip Layup Shot",
                                     "Driving Floating Bank Jump Shot", "Driving Floating Jump Shot", "Jump Bank Shot", "Driving Bank shot",
                                     "Fadeaway Jump Shot", "Floating Jump shot", "Jump Shot", "Pullup Bank shot", "Pullup Jump shot",
                                     "Running Jump Shot", "Running Pull-Up Jump Shot",
                                     "Step Back Jump shot", "Turnaround Bank shot", "Turnaround Fadeaway shot", "Turnaround Jump Shot",
                                     "Hook Bank Shot", "Hook Shot", "Driving Bank Hook Shot", "Driving Hook Shot", "Turnaround Hook Shot"),
                           New.Title = c(rep("Alley Oop", 2),
                                         rep("Dunk", 6),
                                         rep("Layup", 11),
                                         rep("Jump Shot", 15),
                                         rep("Hook Shot",5),
                                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: You can format code by selecting it and then pressing CTRL+K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shot.lookup <-data.frame(Title = c("Alley Oop Dunk Shot", "Alley Oop Layup shot", "Cutting Dunk Shot", "Driving Dunk Shot", "Dunk Shot", "Putback Dunk Shot", "Running Dunk Shot", "Tip Dunk Shot", "Driving Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Driving Reverse Layup Shot","Layup Shot", "Putback Layup Shot", "Reverse Layup Shot", "Cutting Layup Shot", "Running Finger Roll Layup Shot", "Running Layup Shot", "Driving Layup Shot", "Tip Layup Shot", "Driving Floating Bank Jump Shot", "Driving Floating Jump Shot", "Jump Bank Shot", "Driving Bank shot", "Fadeaway Jump Shot", "Floating Jump shot", "Jump Shot", "Pullup Bank shot", "Pullup Jump shot", "Running Jump Shot", "Running Pull-Up Jump Shot", "Step Back Jump shot", "Turnaround Bank shot", "Turnaround Fadeaway shot", "Turnaround Jump Shot", "Hook Bank Shot", "Hook Shot", "Driving Bank Hook Shot", "Driving Hook Shot", "Turnaround Hook Shot"), New.Title = **c(rep("Alley Oop", 2), rep("Dunk", 6), rep("Layup", 11), rep("Jump Shot", 15), rep("Hook Shot",5))**, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

You were missing a parenthesis?